# htaccess Multiple Conditions for RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to reduce these lines?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest1.test.de
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest2.test.de
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest3.test.de
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
```

I want `subtest[1-3].test.de` all to use `robots_testing.txt`.

It already works, but is there a way to combine the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest1.test.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest2.test.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subtest3.test.de
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
```

or even (but I find this less readable)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subtest[1|2|3]\.test\.de$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
```

Comment: `[1|2|3]` - or even `[1-3]` (as the OP "suggested"). Just a thought... if there is only 1 domain (ie. `test.de`) then maybe you only need to check for the subdomain? eg. `^subtest[1-3]\.`